# How to make a template like this using xepersian?

Tags: two-column, templates, xepersian

How to make a template latex like the one below? Abstract should be in a single column, but the entire document in two columns.

[image]

I found a template like this in web, but with the `xepersian` package all of them will be ruined.

Here's an [example template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/astronomy-%26-astrophysics).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had some issues with that template, so here's a solution with the `article` class. I have used `10pt` to fit the example in a single page, but you can use `12pt` too, for example.

Please note that I don't speak Fārsī, so there might be mistakes in the title, author or even the date, although I tried to check to the best of my abilities and everything seems OK. Also let me know if the text is created properly: letters, ligatures, etc.

Remember that you must use the `xelatex` engine.

Here's the output:

[image]

And here's the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % margins
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol} % for text in multiple columns
\usepackage{ptext} % random text generator
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Nazanin}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\setmainlanguage{farsi}
%\setotherlanguage{english}

\title{کاربردی می باشد. کتابهای زیادی}

\date{\today}
\author{فلان جا \\ user1@email.com \and فلان جا \\ user2@email.com}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\ptext[2] % generates a single paragraph of random text
\end{abstract}
\section{توسط فرم زیر می توانید متن ساختگی}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\ptext[1-9] % generates several paragraphs of random text
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you  it is almost the right! If I have a question I will ask in another one. thanks a lot

Comment: @hosseinbehboodi You're welcome! :)

Comment: Just a question: Like the template I want a dash after section number, how can I do this?

Comment: @hosseinbehboodi Sorry, I was not here. You need to load the `titlesec` package, and then in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`), add the command `\titlelabel{\thetitle--\quad}`. Let me know if you manage to do it.

Comment: It works as well as your code :)